# What probability distribution would be look like this?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, mathematical-modeling

I was playing with R, I started with adding consecutive binomials (the n parameter of the second binomial depends of the result of the first binomial and so on...). After a few more operations I got this histogram. I was trying to model something.

This is just me having "fun". After a few frustrating attempts, I gave up on deriving a theoretical distribution for it.

I decided to simply pick a distribution have a fit, and see if I  can justify. But even for this I am stuck! I tried a few, but none of them seem to have the right combination of skewness, mean and variance.

To sum up, the question is simple, do you know any probability distribution shaped like this (continuous or discrete)? (this histogram is for a discrete distribution, the frequencies before 3 are 0, and 7 gave me 1))

[image]

Comment: So you have $X_i \sim B(m,p)$ for some parameters $m$ and $p$, and want to know the distribution of $Z_n = X_1 + ... + X_n$ ? Or something like $X_{i+1} \sim B(X_i,p)$ and their sum? (forgive the weird notation)

Comment: Actually, I have Yi given by B(Y_{i-1},p), and then X is another random variable depending of a calculation from the partial sums of Yi. But I'm ok with not deriving the true probability. Just looking for a similar shaped distribution

Comment: There is a statistics subsite on stackexchange: https://stats.stackexchange.com/. You might get answer here but I'd bet you have a higher probability of getting an answer there.

Comment: I'll try if it does not work here. Thanks! But I have limited knowledge of probability distributions so I'm sure there is a classic distribution that has the right shape